# How to receive the contents of a POST from an external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post

The [Houdini API](http://houdiniapi.com/) sends postbacks that look like this:

```
{
  "api_key": "keykeykeykeykey",
  "environment": "production",
  "postback_url": "http://example.com/postbacks",
  "blueprint": "research_link_data",
  "input": {
    "name": "example name"
    "website": "example website"
  }
  "status": "processing",
  "output": {
    "Correction": "example Correction"
    "has_book": "example has_book"
    "search_results_link": "example search_results_link"
  }
}
```

(With a real API_Key.)

(You set the `postback_url` yourself when you send your initial request to the API.)

To receive and process these postbacks, I have:

```
class Postback < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :uuid
  belongs_to :survey
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :uuid
  after_create :generate_uuid
  def generate_uuid
    self.update_attributes :uuid => SecureRandom.uuid
  end
end

class PostbacksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  def receive
    @postback = Postback.find(params[:id])
  end
end

Testivate::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :postbacks, :only => [:index, :show] do
    member do
      post :receive
    end
  end
end
```

In [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-rest-client/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb?hl=en), I have:

1. Selected the POST radio button
2. Entered "http etc postbacks/32e5a1bb-452f-4ad2-9a42-c17239f3d964/receive as the URL (that's a real UUID, and sorry StackOverflow won't let me post a full local URL)
3. Left the Header field blank (as I don't know what to put there)
4. Put the following into the data field:

   {"api_key": "keykeykeykeykey",
    "environment": "production",
    "postback_url": url,
    "blueprint": "research_link_data",
   "input": {
     "name": "example name"
     "website": "example website"}
     "status": "processing",
     "output": {
       "Correction": "example Correction"
       "has_book": "example has_book"
       "search_results_link": "example search_results_link"}}

(The URL was the same one I listed above in Step 2. StackOverflow didn't like URLs that point to local servers sorry. And sorry I couldn't get StackOverflow to format that as a code block.)

I then dropped into the `postbacks#receive` action using Pry. Why do I just see:

```
> params
=> {"action"=>"receive",
 "controller"=>"postbacks",
 "id"=>"32e5a1bb-452f-4ad2-9a42-c17239f3d964"}
```

How do I get to the rest of my results?

Thanks,

Steven.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial on simple-rest-client](http://programmingnotes.thinktanktheory.com/chrome-simple-rest-client/) implies that you have to set the header field to make a form-post work:

"add Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded to the Header"

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for the link. Tried that and will do that for now on. But the params I receive are no different to what I was receiving already.

Comment: Cool. The dodgy screenshot on that page also seems to imply that you should use url-encoded format in the data-field eg "key=value&other_key=other_value" rather than the hash-syntax you're using. (note: I'm only guessing)

Comment: Update: If I set the headers to "Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json" I get a "MultiJson::LoadError at /postbacks/32e5a1bb-452f-4ad2-9a42-c17239f3d964/receive... unexpected token" error. Now Googling that one.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to:

1. Ensure the controller responded to JSON (`respond_to :html, :json`)
2. Insert a few commas that were missing from the sample JSON I was trying to receive
3. Set the POST header to `Content-Type: application/json Accept: application/json`